# What is the inverse function of $f(x,y) = (x,y,0)$?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

If $f: A \to B$ is given by $f(x,y) = (x,y,0)$, where $A$ is an open disc in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $B=\{{(x,y,0)}\in \mathbb{R^3} \mid (x,y) \in A\}$ what is its inverse frunction $f^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse is $f^{-1}(x,\,y,\,0)=(x,\,y)$.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear, if we had $f: A \to B$ is given by $f(x,y) = (2x,2y,0)$, where $A$ is an open disc in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $B=\{{(2x, 2y,0)}\in \mathbb{R^3} \mid (x,y) \in A\}$, would you say $f^{-1}(2x,\,2y,\,0)=(x,\,y)$ or $f^{-1}(x,\,y,\,0)=(0.5x,\,0.5y)$?

Comment: @A.B. You could write it either way, but the latter would be typical.